# node.js + express , routers in separated files and middleware only before certain routes?

Tags: node.js, express, middleware

I have Router dynamically generated. Routes files are in folders structure that corresponds to router path. e.g. route `v1/users/getUsers` so getUsers.js is in `/api/v1/users/` folder.

My middle wares are in `/middlewares/` folder, and I am generating my express app  in `/createExpressApp.js`

so currently I have my authorisation middlware in `.use(auth)` just before `.use('/api', router)`
This way it works just fine, before each route , auth is executed. However, I want to protect only certain routes. I guess I could just import my middleware in each file with a route I want to protect, but some of the routes are deep in folders and my import would be something ugly like `../../../middlware/auth.js`

Is there any clever way to avoid that kind of import ?

Here is my router dynamic creation, I do admit I found that solution somewhere on the internet and I do understand idea but don't know where to put some extras for router such as router.all or router.use

```
import { sync } from 'glob'
import { Router } from 'express'

const auth = require('../middlewares/auth.js').isAuthenticated

export default () => sync('**/*.js', { cwd: `${__dirname}/` })
    .map(filename => require(`./${filename}`).default)
    .filter(router => Object.getPrototypeOf(router) == Router)
    .reduce(
      (rootRouter, router) =>rootRouter.use(router),
      Router({ mergeParams: true })
    )
```

so answering my own problem + answer from below using router.all ( or others from documentation). I would put it here:

```js
export default () => sync('**/*.js', { cwd: `${__dirname}/` })
    .map(filename => require(`./${filename}`).default)
    .filter(router => Object.getPrototypeOf(router) == Router)
    .reduce(
      (rootRouter, router) =>rootRouter
      .all('*getUsers',auth)
      .use(router)
      ,
      Router({ mergeParams: true })
    )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Anything clever or configuration based is going to leave you at the same problem: Somewhere you need to describe which routes have auth over them.

It seems the easiest way to do this would be requiring the auth on the routes needed.

You should review the [express middleware documentation](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#router), as you can break up app into different routers and `router.use`.

A typical pattern would be to use the `router.all` to define the endpoints that need auth. You can use regex/route pattern matching, as shown in the linked documentation and in the screenshot below:

[image: on router]

Comment: that looks like exactly what I need. also router.param might be helpful in the future. Thank you

Comment: Np. You might like the last example/pattern of router documentation, which uses `authRouter` and `openRouter`, see end of: https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#router

Comment: It looks good, but because of my project structure, I load all routes dynamically and export them and then .use in express app. I tired before I define express app but after I have a  `var router = require ('./generateRouter.js')`  and then if I do` router.all('*',auth)` that does nothing to the router. Is that the right place to do it ?

Comment: I think you'd want generate the dynamic routes with the calls. Make sure with middleware you remember to call next() as well.

Comment: I have added my router generator function ( which is not really mine), I thought I understand how it works, but now when I need to add those extras to router, I don't know where to do it. Maybe I should actually create normal router